# SAP Desktop shortcut system commands

Tags: transactions, sap-gui, shortcut-file

The shortcut down below is executing the following system command:

```
/n*iw31 AUFPAR-PM_AUFART=PM03;CAUFVD-PRIOK=2;CAUFVD-EQUNR=00000000000000001;RC62C-REFNR=9305432319;
```

[image: SAP shortcut properties]

[image: IW31 filled form]

After clicking the shortcut the following screen pops-up.
After clicking the green check mark IW31 order opens.

[image: Pop-up after shortcut executed]

Now my problem is;
I want this one shortcut to fill in some text fields in the IW31 form, things like PMActType, order title, user status. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: No. A shortcut is just to start something and fill the selection screen.

Comment: is there any other way to make this possible/happen?

Comment: Yes of course, but opinions and links are not suitable for Stack Overflow, so I'll just give some hints and you can search in the Web: SAP GUI Scripting, ABAP Batch Input.